# C++ array of vectors of pointers initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I want to allocate an array of vectors in a function. Every vector should be initiated with a size of 0. Afterwards I want to push pointers to objects T to my vectors. Finally I want have a grid with a list of references in every cell. I am stuck at the initialization of the vectors. It seems that they are not allocated ?

```
typedef std::vector<T*> GridCell;
GridCell* mGrid;

...

int gridSize = 5;
mGrid = new GridCell[gridSize];
mGrid[gridSize] = { GridCell() }; //runtime error here
```

This might be possibly duplicated to other posts, but I couldn't find one that solves this issue 100%.

Comment: As an aside, why not use a `vector<vector<T*>>` instead of a raw pointer to a newed array?

Comment: `mGrid[gridSize]` is one past the end. Valid indices are 0–(`gridSize` - 1).

Comment: @juanchopanza I use an array to preallocate the memory and to make sure the access is threadsafe.

Comment: @Anthea: That makes no sense. `vector` also allocates memory, and access is also thread-safe as long as you don't modify it. It's equivalent to your manual `new`, only without the need to manually clean it up afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mGrid = new GridCell[gridSize];
```

This line not only allocates an array, but it default constructs all of the entries too!

```
mGrid[gridSize]
```

This is an out of bounds error; as the array has length 5, the only valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Trying to access an element at index 5 is *undefined behavior*.

```
vector<GridCell> mGrid(5);
// vector<GridCell> mGrid(5, GridCell()); // Same thing as the line above
```

This is what you should have done instead. With modern C++, it's pretty rare that you should ever have to use `new`; there are standard objects that serve most of the purposes people once used `new` for (e.g. using `vector` instead of dynamically an array), there are smart pointers for most of the remaining cases, and for the few cases still remaining, you're usually better served by writing your own custom class whose purpose in life is to be a wrapper around whatever you're doing with `new`.